# How does elastic potential energy translate into kinetic energy and momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, spring

Let's assume there's a spring with 10,000J of elastic potential energy placed between two objects with a mass of 10kg each. Like this:

10kg< 10,000J >10kg

I assume that the energy would be equally distributed to both objects, thus, both objects would have 5,000J of kinetic energy.

When I solve for the velocity of the object through the formula for kinetic energy (KE = 0.5*10*V^2) I receive 31.622m/s

Plugging this into the formula for momentum gives me an answer of 316.22 kg*m/s

Now, when I solve for the same problem but with one mass being only 1kg, I get a much different momentum, and I'm not sure if I'm thinking about it the wrong way or if my math is incorrect.

10kg< 10,000J >1kg

Since it's 1/10th the mass, I assume that 90% of the energy would go into the 1kg object.

So, 9000J. 
After solving for the velocity, I receive 134.16kg*m/s.

Why is it that despite the energy in the system remaining the same, the momentum can be so different? Is this correct?

Comment: Think carefully about conservation of momentum, as well as conservation of energy. Consider the momentum of each mass, before and after. You should be able to write down two equations: one for the total energy, one for the total momentum.

Answer (score 0):

> Since it's 1/10th the mass, I assume that 90% of the energy would go into the 1kg object.

is not a correct assumption and you should start with a consideration of momentum conservation to relate the final speeds of the two objects.

If the masses of the two objects are $m$ and $M$ then the fraction of the total energy stored in the spring which the object mass $m$ takes as kinetic energy can be shown to be $\dfrac{M}{m+M}$ which is $\dfrac {10}{10+1} \times 100 = 90.9\%$ in your example.

---

Now consider an extreme case of one end of the compressed spring being connected to a wall (and the Earth) mass $M$ and the other end to an object mass $m$.
The magnitude of the final momentum of the wall and of the object will be the same but the kinetic energy of the wall will be negligible compared with that of the wall because the mass of the wall is so much greater than that of the object $(m\ll M)$ ie the kinetic energy of the object is equal to the elastic potential energy stored in the spring to a very good approximation.